# Compass is creating the same sprite map multiple times

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

This is resulting in an insane compile time: ~20 seconds. Notice that it creates the global-s9e3ed7fd2e.png image 5 times, as opposed to just once for mobile & once for desktop.

I only see `@import "sprites/global/*.png";` being called twice, hence my confusion.

Here's the config file: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D22jy/)

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using Grunt so you might want to show your gruntfile.js as it could be causing the problem.

Comment: Heads up, this is part of a gigantic repo which I am still trying to navigate fluidly.

So, I can see about 10 different gruntfile.js files in this repo, all within the node_modules folder. 

Would the grunthelpers.js file be of more use?

Comment: Wait, just realized that you want the config file. Added to original post in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `force:false` on your compass config options, there was a previous issue that caused sprites to be regenerated.

Compilation with Compass and sprites is slow regardless. I had a similar problem: [Grunt with Compass and Watch compiles slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666237/grunt-with-compass-and-watch-compiles-slow)

Comment: Yeah, turns out the issue was simply the fact that we were generating so many sprite sheets. Bundled some, removed others, and the compile time dropped drastically.